# How to fetch a git remote but only change files that have not been altered in the local repository?

Tags: git

Say I have two repositories: Project A and Project B. Project B has a remote of Project A. I've been working on both projects simultaneously. Now I want the changes from A to go into B, but I don't want files that have been changed from A to be over written. In B I have projects A's files, some files from A originally that have been changed since being in B, and new files that only B has. The files that have not been changed in B from A I want to have updated with the new changes from A. How should I do this?

#### edit

Maybe what I want is

```sh
# from B on master
git remote update a
git rebase --onto a/master
```

The only problem is that if B has a lot of changes which conflict with a/master how do I order git to always take the current branch's version of the file over the remote's?

Comment: Git has support for this kind of workflow through branches, but if you have multiple repositories you might be out of luck.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Is there not way to give local changes priority when doing a fetch or pull?

Comment: @JohnSmith Save changed files, fetch, restore. Like in `git stash push && git pull && git stash pop` or simply `git pull --autostash`

Comment: @phd Would that work if the remote is already merged into B?

Comment: @JohnSmith No, there will be a warning from `pull` "The branch is up to date".

Comment: Note that `git remote update <remote>` is just a longer way to run `git fetch <remote>`. The `git remote` command has extra support for fancier operations, but in this case `a` is just the name of a remote, so you're not invoking the fancier stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Nohow

**Longer answer**

Re-think your "workflow". Chaotic changes and jumping between (related be code) projects are a direct way to unmaintained disorder. **The Right Way (tm)** is (somehow):

- Do something in repo A
- Commit & push work
- Switch to repo B
- Pull
- Merge pulled (maybe with special merge-driver)

Comment: I'm sorry that really off base from what I need. Really I just need git to remember what was the first commit in the remote having repo and only rebase sub-set to that commit.